# Alter Multiple Field Values by Testing "Field Type"

Tags: 8, hooks

Drupal 8.x

I would like to alter the value of all/any ckeditor/text fields on a node.

Currently working with [HOOK_node_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.5.x).

Ideally, I'd like an agnostic approach that doesn't mind where the field is coming from, e.g. paragraph, node, taxonomy, etc.

How can I loop through all fields, check the field type, get and replace the value?

---

**MYMODULE.module**

Working with the below code gets me close I think:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

function MYMODULE_node_presave(EntityInterface $entity) {
  $fieldsArray = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldMapByFieldType('text_long');

  foreach($fieldsArray as $longTextName=>$key) {

    kpr($key); // This returns an array of the values I need.
    if ($entity->hasField($key)) {
      $entity->get($result)->value = preg_replace(
        $toReplace,
        $replaceWith,
        $entity->get($result)->value
      );
    }
  }

}
```

---

Try #2;

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function MYMODULE_presave(EntityInterface $entity) {
  // Get form config.
  // Get config Node field names.
  // Get config Paragraph names.
  // Get config Paraghraph field names.

  // Loop through our Node field names.
  foreach($nodeFieldNames as $fieldName) {
    // Check if the entity has field.
    if ($entity->hasField($fieldName)) {
      // Get the field.
      $entity->get($fieldName)->value = $newValue;
    }
  }

  // Loop through our Paragraph names.
  foreach($paragraphNames as $paragraphName) {
  // Check if the entity has field.
  if ($entity->hasField($paragraphName)) {
    $paragraphs = $entity->$paragraphName->getValue();
    foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraphItem) {
      $p = \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph::load( $paragraphItem['target_id'] );
      foreach($paragraphFieldNames as $paragraphFieldNamesitem) {
        if ($p->get($paragraphFieldNamesitem)->value) {
          // kpr($p->get($paragraphFieldNamesitem)->value);
          $p->get($paragraphFieldNamesitem)->value = $newvalue;
          // kpr($p->get($paragraphFieldNamesitem)->value);
          // This does alter the value, just does not get saved.
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In general this code looks like it belongs in a text filter. For the agnostic way on a field type basis you could extend the field widget of this field type.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on the "looks like it belongs in a text filter"? Not sure I follow and would like to...

Comment: Create a custom text filter and add it to the text format(s) used in the field.

Comment: That is definitely a viable option using the text filters. Not the path for me currently, but a good Drupal way to do it. Great thinking!

Comment: I've continued to work on this and can say that creating a custom text filter was by far the easiest/best approach for my use case. This doesn't really answer the question, but is the best way for me to go! For others here, issues I faced were that paragraphs use subforms, and I couldn't alter field values via HOOK_entity_presave(). Similar issue with the comment field. Not saying it can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FieldConfigInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldConfigInterface.php/8.2.x) to get fields info.
Try the following:

```
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldConfigInterface;

function MYMODULE_node_presave($node) {
  //- Call helper function to get all the fields
  $fieldsArray = getContentTypeFields($node->bundle());
  //- Loop through fields 
  foreach ($fieldsArray as $fieldName => $fieldConfig) {
    ///- Example to check if type is text_with_summary
    if ($fieldConfig->getType() == 'text_with_summary') {
      /**
       * @TODO : Something here for field of type text_with_summary
       */
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Helper function to Get all fields of content type:
 *
 * @param $contentType
 *
 * @return array
 */
function getContentTypeFields($contentType) {
  $entityManager = Drupal::service('entity.manager');
  $fields = [];
  if (!empty($contentType)) {
    $fields = array_filter(
      $entityManager->getFieldDefinitions('node', $contentType), function ($field_definition) {
      return $field_definition instanceof FieldConfigInterface;
    }
    );
  }

  return $fields;
}
```

Comment: This works well for node, yet it does not return fields from paragraph, comment, etc.

Comment: you are welcome you can adjust the function on your needs. i thought that you need only for nodes.

Comment: I've been working with your answer, and have had some success, but just can't seem to accomplish the final step. Above code may be a little messy right now but feels close. I think maybe if this works for node and paragraph, it could easily for comment fields, etc. Right now I am just using the single helper function.